# css background colour

Tags: html, css

My CSS file contains my webpage display, the webpage is smaller than the screen (if you know what i mean) I am trying to fill the outside of my container with a background colour but it is not working. Can anybody help with this?
here is my CSS

```
    #container  {
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

The body/ navigation etc are below the #container, does the background colour have to be before the container? I have placed it there and it is not working?

Comment: Some HTML code would go a long way to helping us figure out what exactly you're trying to do. From what I gather from a comment below, you're not trying to change the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

body {} in the css refers to the complete < body > of the website. Just set the background-color there, like:

```
body {background-color: #fedae3;}
```

of course, the container needs another background-color.

Answer (score 4):

You could apply it to the body?

```
body {
  background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: This only adds the colour to the #body section of the webpage its outside the container I want to apply the color to. thanks for your help!